# Is there a simple way to calculate minutes between two date_times, excluding a specific interval?

Tags: r, difftime

```
start                   End                  minutes
2019-01-11 14:36:00     2019-01-13 16:27:00  2991
```

What I want is to calculate minutes excluding the interval between 00:00 and 06:00.

Comment: So do you want to exclude both days (12-01 & 13-01's time intervals) for the given example?  What's the expected output for this example?

Answer (score 1):

```
interval_time_excluded=as.numeric(round(difftime("2019-01-13 16:27:00", "2019-01-11 14:36:00", units = "days")))*as.difftime(c("06:00:00", "00:00:00"), units = "mins")[1]
interval_time_excluded
# output : Time difference of 720 mins
difftime("2019-01-13 16:27:00", "2019-01-11 14:36:00", units = "mins")
# output : Time difference of 2991 mins
difftime("2019-01-13 16:27:00", "2019-01-11 14:36:00", units = "mins")-interval_time_excluded
# Your desired output : Time difference of 2271 mins
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. For this specific case it works fine. However I have a huge database with several combinations and using your solution it does not work fine.
For example,
Start                                 End                              minutes
2019-02-17 00:04:00 2019-02-17 06:56:00    56

Comment: @JoséCampelo , plz give a sample of your data ! use `dput(head(your_data_name))`. Update your post by adding the sample !

Comment: Something like this? I'm new in stack  and I dont know how actually this works
structure(list(BLOCK_DATE_TIME.x = structure(c(1547217360, 1547225100, 
1547392800, 1554900060, 1555930500, 1556305620), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), BLOCK_DATE_TIME.y = structure(c(1547396820, 
1547228280, 1547397600, 1554905520, 1555936980, 1556362320), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @JoséCampelo , pb solved ! Plz click on ✓ mark to accept the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Your post question is simple , just you need more practise with R functions like `apply` :

```
end_date="2019-01-11 14:36:00"
start_date="2019-01-13 16:27:00"
start_date_excluded="00:00:00"
end_date_excluded="06:00:00"


diff_times<-function(start_date="2019-01-13 16:27:00",end_date="2019-01-11 14:36:00",start_date_excluded="00:00:00",end_date_excluded="06:00:00"){
        interval_time_excluded=as.numeric(round(difftime(start_date, end_date, units = "days")))*as.difftime(c(end_date_excluded, start_date_excluded), units = "mins")[1]
        # interval_time_excluded
        # output : Time difference of 720 mins
    
    # part for the special case 
# part for the special case 
if(round(difftime(start_date, end_date, units = "days"))==0){
   

if(c(as.numeric(lubridate::hour(start_date))+1)==as.numeric(substr(end_date_excluded,1,2)) & as.numeric(substr(start_date_excluded,1,2))==as.numeric(lubridate::hour(end_date))) { 
      return(0)   
    }else{
        return(difftime(start_date, end_date, units = "mins"))
    }  
}

# part for the special case

    # part for the special case
    
    # difftime(start_date, end_date, units = "mins")
    # output : Time difference of 2991 mins
    return(difftime(start_date, end_date, units = "mins")-interval_time_excluded)
        # Your desired output : Time difference of 2271 mins
        
}
    
    

    diff_times()  # An example of a running using the default entered function values
    
    data=structure(list(BLOCK_DATE_TIME.x = structure(c(1547217360, 1547225100, 1547392800, 1554900060, 1555930500, 1556305620), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), BLOCK_DATE_TIME.y = structure(c(1547396820, 1547228280, 1547397600, 1554905520, 1555936980, 1556362320), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") 

    apply(data, 1 , function(x) return(diff_times(x[2],x[1],start_date_excluded="00:00:00",end_date_excluded="06:00:00")))  # The result using your data ( returned as a vector )
```

This output :

```
Time difference of 2271 mins
   1    2    3    4    5    6 
2271   53   80   91  108  585
```

Examples for special cases :

```
diff_times(start_date="2019-01-09 05:59:00",end_date="2019-01-09 00:00:00",start_date_excluded="00:00:00",end_date_excluded="06:00:00")

diff_times(start_date="2019-01-09 07:59:00",end_date="2019-01-09 00:00:00",start_date_excluded="00:00:00",end_date_excluded="06:00:00")

[1] 0
Time difference of 479 mins
```

Comment: Thanks again. However I tried to apply your function to my DF with more than 200k lines and I found the following case:

364 2019-01-09 00:00:00 2019-01-09 05:59:00 359

In this case the result should be zero because is in the interval [00:00-06:00]

Comment: Your data isn't properly formated ! if you're using excel , try to format it in the same manner as in your example ! After that , import your data to R and run the function !

Comment: Are you sure? I try to run your diff_times function but with this new example and the result is 359 minutes.

`diff_times<-function(start_date="2019-01-09 05:59:00",end_date="2019-01-09 00:00:00",start_date_excluded="00:00:00",end_date_excluded="06:00:00")
{
  interval_time_excluded=as.numeric(round(difftime(start_date, end_date, units = "days")))*as.difftime(c(end_date_excluded, start_date_excluded), units = "mins")[1]
 
  return(difftime(start_date, end_date, units = "mins")-interval_time_excluded)
Time difference of 359 mins
  
}`

Comment: @JoséCampelo , i updated the answer ! Try it again , it will give you `0` for the cases when we're comparing the same days !

Comment: is not that simple. For same day we can actually have calculated minutes because is in the interval [06:01-23:59].  See 2nd example of the output vector that you posted before.

Comment: @JoséCampelo , this requires some reflexion , I updated the post again ! I hope this helps you solving the pb !

Comment: Thanks again. I think your solution does not cover every cases in my DF. Nevertheless your solution it will be very helpfull to solve my complex problem.

Comment: @JoséCampelo , i updated the answer for the last time ! Now , I think it works well for special cases !